# Делаю адаптацию, все на слайдере плывет как устранить?

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]http://www.twelfth-site.ho.ua/

Добрый день! Делаю адаптацию, все на слайдере плывет и вылазит за рамки картинки, на скриншоте видно,  как устранить ?

Comment: Использовать `media` запросы и через них менять значения для свойст позиционирования. Или убрать этот ужас из абсолютых елементов и сделать нормальный блок. И потом уже его так же через `media` исправлять

Answer (score 1):

Используете медиа-запросы.
Так же рекомендую сделать, то что предложил @E_K : уберите абсолютные элементы, и сделайте блок. Будет проще всё это отследить.
Добавлю от себя: советую использовать Grid (Адаптивная сетка). Ссылка: [тык](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout).

```css
  // Ландшафтный экран телефоны
  @media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
 
  // От ландшафтного экрана телефона до потретного планшета
  @media (max-width: 767px) { ... }
 
  // От портретного планшета до ландшафтного экрана и настольных дисплеев
  @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }
 
  // Большой дисплей
  @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```